# Extracting from file lines from datablocks in a given range, and within a given line range in each block

Tags: text-processing

I have a data file of this form

```
1 4
2 0
2 3
3 5
5 3
8 12
2 3
3 5
5 3
0 -1
2 4
33 3
```

The file has 12 lines, which should be interpreted as four consecutive datablocks of 3 lines each. For example, the third block is

```
2 3
3 5
5 3
```

How may I extract lines from i to j in each block, in blocks from m to n, and output them in a file in linux?

For example, for `i=2`, `j=3`, `m=1`, `n=3`, the desired result should look like

```
2 0
2 3
5 3
8 12
3 5
5 3
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The following `awk` program should do:

```
awk -v bs=3 -v i=2 -v j=3 -v m=1 -v n=3 '(FNR/bs>m-1) && (FNR/bs<=n) && ((FNR-1)%bs>=i-1) && ((FNR-1)%bs<j)' input.txt
```

This will import your key data as `awk` variables into the program:

- the blocksize as variable `bs`
- the start and end block numbers as variables `m` and `n`
- the start and end line numbers as variables `i` and `j`

It uses the `awk` logic that any condition outside of "rule" blocks that evaluates to `true` (or non-zero) instructs `awk` to print the current line.

Printing is based on the automatic variable `FNR`, representing the per-file line counter. Your requirements basically amount to identifying the block number by dividing `FNR` number by the block size, and the line within the block by calculating the modulus of the `FNR` (for convenience, we use `FNR-1` which starts at 0), and then formulating a boolean expression that is only `true` for those lines you want printed.

**Update**

The program may be "sped up" by avoiding time-consuming operations whenever possible. To do so, you can amend the program as follows:

```
awk ... 'BEGIN{first=bs*(m-1)+1; last=bs*n}
         FNR<first{next}
         FNR>last{exit}
         ((FNR-1)%bs>=i-1) && ((FNR-1)%bs<j)' input.txt
```

This will first determine the first and last lines to consider.

- If the current line number is before the beginning of the first block, we immediately skip to the next line and don't perform any of the calculations and comparisons for the "fine-grained" check on whether to print.
- Similarly, if the current line number ist past the last block to consider, we immediately terminate the program.
- Only if we are inside the "region of interest" the arithmetic operations to check which lines to print are performed.

That way, we can keep calculations to an absolute minimum.

If you are using the GNU variant of `awk`, and you have specified several input files as arguments, use `nextfile` instead of `exit` to skip to the next file rather then exit the program.

Comment: Thank you @AdminBee, this works like a charm and your explanation is very clear. However, I find that the code is very slow on the actual file which I am using (block size = 360, 90 blocks). Is there a way to speed it up? Thanks

Comment: There is no way that code is slow, it'll be extremely fast. Are you calling it repeatedly from inside a shell loop or something? If so that calling loop is what's slow, not the awk script, and the solution would probably be to call a different awk script once to do everything you need all at the same time rather than call it repeatedly within a loop but you'd have to ask a new, followup question about that.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I am not calling the awk script from inside a shell loop. And yes, the awk script is slow. Besides, slow or fast depends on the size of the data file that one is using it with.

Comment: No, that awk script is not slow. It's doing a single pass of the input, storing almost nothing in memory with no loops or anything else that would make it slow. A script that takes a long time to run on massive data does not mean `the code is very slow`, it just means there's a lot of data to get through and that will take time even when the code is very fast.

Comment: Like I said, slow or fast depends on the size of the data file. You should read previous comments before you post yours.

Comment: @Pascal I have added a "streamlined" version of the program; perhaps that can help a little.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with GNU sed and awk:

```
# Split data into data-blocks
<infile sed '3~3G'                              |

# Only pass blocks m through n onwards
awk 'NR >= m && NR <= n' RS= ORS='\n\n' m=1 n=3 |

# Only print lines i through j within each block
awk '{ for (x=i ; x<=j; x++) print $x }' RS= FS='\n' i=2 j=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU sed with the separate stream option (-s) to handle multiple files in its command line as individual files.

```
i=2 j=3 m=1 n=3 G=3
split -l "$G" file
printf '%s\n' x?* |
sed -e "$m,$n!d;${n}q" |
xargs sed -s "$i,$j!d"
```

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
$ paste - - - < file | sed -n 1,3p | cut -f 2-3 | tr '\t' '\n'
2 0
2 3
5 3
8 12
3 5
5 3
```

Or, parameterized:

```bsh
$ i=2 j=3 m=1 n=3
$ paste - - - < file | sed -n "$m,${n}p" | cut -f "$i-$j" | tr '\t' '\n'
2 0
2 3
5 3
8 12
3 5
5 3
```

Explained:

- The first `paste` command creates a line per "block" with tab-delimited fields:

  ```bsh
  $ paste - - - < file
  1 4     2 0     2 3
  3 5     5 3     8 12
  2 3     3 5     5 3
  0 -1    2 4     33 3
  ```
- With `sed`, we pick out the blocks (lines of output from `paste`) that we're interested in.  Here we want lines 1 through to 3, inclusively:

  ```bsh
  $ paste - - - < file | sed -n 1,3p
  1 4     2 0     2 3
  3 5     5 3     8 12
  2 3     3 5     5 3
  ```
- The `cut` command selects what bits of each block we want. The `paste` utility produces tab-delimited output by default, and `cut` cuts on tabs by default. This cuts out columns 2 thorough to 3 inclusively:

  ```bsh
  $ paste - - - < file | sed -n 1,3p | cut -f 2-3
  2 0     2 3
  5 3     8 12
  3 5     5 3
  ```
- The final `tr` reverses the effect of the initial `paste` for the remaining data:

  ```bsh
  $ paste - - - < file | sed -n 1,3p | cut -f 2-3 | tr '\t' '\n'
  2 0
  2 3
  5 3
  8 12
  3 5
  5 3
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -e '.join("\n").put for lines.rotor(3)[0..2].map(*.[1..2]);'
```

Sample Input:

```
1 4
2 0
2 3
3 5
5 3
8 12
2 3
3 5
5 3
0 -1
2 4
33 3
```

Sample Output:

```
2 0
2 3
5 3
8 12
3 5
5 3
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, `lines` are read in (lazily), and `rotor`-ed (i.e. grouped) together in exact groups of `3` lines each (incomplete groups at the end will be dropped with the code above, if you want partial groups returned add the correct 'adverb' option, like so: `rotor(3, :partial)`).

The first 3 groups of three lines are retained (using the `[0..2]` indexing construct), and `map(*.[1..2])` performs mapping within these three groups to return only the second and third elements (Perl-family languages like Raku start indexing from zero).

The above code returns the desired result, however if the programmer wants, results can be returned linewise/quoted, like so:

```perl
raku -e '.raku.put for lines.rotor(3)[0..2].map(*.[1..2]);'  file
("2 0", "2 3")
("5 3", "8 12")
("3 5", "5 3")
```

https://raku.org